# Disable Certificate Revocation in vyatta ipsec vpn

Tags: vpn, ipsec, vyatta

I have a problem where the VPN on a road warrior configuration.

our windows hosts work fine.

our mac's don't work so well.

**Errors from StrongSwan:** 
ocsp status is stale or not in cache 
crl not found 
certificate status unknown 
issuer cacert not found 
X.509 certificate rejected

There is apparently a function in strongswan to disable the revocation module, i can't find where sadly.

Answer (score 0):

- there is *charon.load* option in *strongswan.conf* file.
  you can manually specify plugin list there, omitting the *revocation* plugin. but read [this](http://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/PluginLoad) first.
- you can try disabling this module during compilation `./configure --disable-revocation`